custom dropdown with (radio buttons & checkboxes) in react. possible?
I have been trying to find if there is a custom third party library for a unique scenario i am in. Snapshot of the dropdown is attached.
Tried checking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiselect-react-dropdown but they donot have such a scenario
Basically, this is how it works. User can either select Test or Prod Based on the radio button selections, i will be making a call to backend and get array of releases. Those will be displayed below the radio buttons. User can then select/ deselect any of the checkboxes. Does anyone know if there is a 3rd party library that can help mimic this scenario.
If not, can someone shed some light on how we can develop a custom dropdown like this. I dont want the code but i just need some guidance on how to achieve this.

Hi @ArenTrot — asking for recommendations for third-party libraries isn't on topic for SO, but you can edit the question to show the code you've written and to focus on a specific part of the implementation that is blocking you. See [ask] for more info.

Have you tried using a form (like a bootstrap form: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/forms/checks-radios/) inside the dropdown? You might require to add some logic to handle that when the radio button is selected, the checkboxes need to be disabled and viceversa. You can do this handling the state of each element in such form.
